# Not able to see items in ListView android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I want to display items in list view dynamically. In my case items comes from the service. Service broadcast the item and the activity receives it and fill the array for item, that array I use to fill up the list view.

Could you please help me to know what I am doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
public class MacaddressInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listofMac=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_macaddress_info);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("intMAC"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            handleMessage(intent);
        }
    };

    private void handleMessage(Intent msg){
        if(msg != null) {
            Bundle data = msg.getExtras();
            String res = data.getString("result");
            Log.d("macaddinfo", "macaddress info is: " + res);

            listofMac.add(res);

            lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstMac);
            adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listofMac);
            setListAdapter(adapter);

            Log.i("handlemessage", "Array count is: " + listofMac.size() + " ListView count is: " + lv.getCount());

        }
    }

    protected ListView getListView() {
        if (lv == null) {
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMac);
        }
        return lv;
    }

    protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

In onhandlemessage() method, I am filling the array and setting up the adapter, but I am not sure why list view is not showing on the screen. Even I am getting the count also, "I/handlemessage: Array count is: 1 ListView count is: 1"

Below is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="rockwell.bluetooth_pairing.MacaddressInfo"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_macaddress_info">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lstMac"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code of service which broadcast the intent that will use as a values of list view

```
public class APIService extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        APIService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return APIService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void AddMacAddress(String str)
    {
        Log.d("APIService","message is: " + str);
        Intent intent = new Intent("intMAC");
        intent.putExtra("result",str);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.d("APIService", "intent broadcasted");
    }
}
```

Code to call the service

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<String> listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int clickCounter=0;
    ListView lv;
    EditText txtIP;
    Button btnAdd,btnUpdate,btnDel;
    int itemPos;

    APIService mservice;
    boolean mBound = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        txtIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtIP);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                txtIP.setText(listItems.get(position));
                itemPos = position;
                Log.d("onlongclickpos", "long click pos is: " + position);
                return true;
            }
        });
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MacaddressInfo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                mservice.AddMacAddress("TestMAC");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, APIService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // Unbind from the service
        if (mBound) {
            unbindService(mConnection);
            mBound = false;
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            APIService.LocalBinder binder = (APIService.LocalBinder) service;
            mservice = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
    public void addItems(View v) {
        txtIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtIP);
        String strItem = txtIP.getText().toString();
        listItems.add(strItem);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void updateItem(View v) {
        //txtIP = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtIP);
        String strItem = txtIP.getText().toString();
        //Toast.makeText(this,"pos is " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        int pos = itemPos;
        if(pos > -1) {
            adapter.remove(listItems.get(pos));
            adapter.insert(strItem, pos);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    public void delItem(View v) {
        //int pos = lv.getCheckedItemPosition();
        int pos = itemPos;
        if(pos>-1)
        {
            adapter.remove(listItems.get(pos));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    protected ListView getListView() {
        if (lv == null) {
            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
        }
        return lv;
    }

    protected void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    protected ListAdapter getListAdapter() {
        ListAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
        if (adapter instanceof HeaderViewListAdapter) {
            return ((HeaderViewListAdapter)adapter).getWrappedAdapter();
        } else {
            return adapter;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `data.getString("result")` returning an empty string?

Comment: nope, it's not returning empty, it has the proper data in it to fill in list view

Comment: Please include the adapter and layout for your list view items

Comment: @ChrisWilson -  The Adapter is a generic String Adapter with the layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` ... it isn't custom

Comment: @MMJ - I don't understand BroadcastReceivers too well, but how does the code ever get to `handleMessage`? I see `registerReceiver`, but what triggers `onReceive`?

Comment: Broadcastreceiver receives the intent from the service. Answer to your question, yes code regularly goes into the handlemessage() and I can see the log also the count of array and count of list view

Comment: Log.i("handlemessage", "Array count is: " + listofMac.size() + " ListView count is: " + lv.getCount()); - This returns the value I/handlemessage: Array count is: 3 ListView count is: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning and initializing your views and adapters first in `onCreate`, then in `handleMessage`, you can add to the list and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to tell the adapter to update the ListView.

Also, after some work, making `listOfMac` static ending up solving the problem. I think what was happening before in the logs was you were holding onto old instances of the `MacAddressInfo` class, and so it was those `ListView` counts that were incrementing, not the currently displayed one.

Code looks like this

```
public class MacAddressActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Static variables shared at class-level
    private static final ArrayList<String> listofMac = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static boolean mRegistered;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ListView lv;

    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            handleMessage(intent);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_macaddress_info);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMac);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listofMac);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // fab code

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // prevent from registering again
        if (!mRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("intMAC"));
            mRegistered = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Should be unregistered, but uncommenting this makes it stop working
        /*
        if (mRegistered) {
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
            mRegistered = false;
        }
        */
    }

    private void handleMessage(Intent msg) {
        if (msg != null) {
            Bundle data = msg.getExtras();
            String res = data.getString("result");
            Log.d("macaddinfo", "macaddress info is: " + res);

            listofMac.add(res);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.i("handlemessage", "Array count is: " + listofMac.size() + " ListView count is: " + lv.getCount());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's not binding the listview. Even in the log it displays like I/handlemessage: Array count is: 3 ListView count is: 0

Comment: My service broadcast the intent like this 
        `Intent intent = new Intent("intMAC");
        intent.putExtra("result",str);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
        Log.d("APIService", "intent broadcasted"); `
and Activity receives this broadcasted intent

Comment: I've edited your question to include that code, but if you could provide what class that is in and what the value of `str` is, that would be better.

Comment: I am sorry I am not getting you exactly, but i can tell you that the value of str is `"test"` also, the code which I mentioned in my comment is from the Service, which broadcast the value of list view

Comment: I have updated my main questions and added the code for the service also

Comment: @MMJ Can I ask why you need a Service at all? Why can't you just do `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter().getAddress()`?

Comment: I need to build an API call so that this function can be called from everywhere in the application. Apart from this, I dont't know how to use BluetoothAdapter

Comment: Based on the package name you are trying to get the MAC Addresses of Bluetooth devices, yes? Not the wifi MAC? And `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` can be called from everywhere.

Comment: yes, but as per the architecture of the system ,we need to define a service for that and need to use it..

Comment: I have updated my main questions from where I am calling the service with this line `mservice.AddMacAddress("TestMAC");`

Comment: Thanks again. So... You are trying to communicate across Activities? If the `MacaddressInfo` activity isn't created yet, then how is the ListView supposed to be updated?

Comment: How can I check whether the activity is created or not? Also, I have call the service after i started the activity                                                        `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MacaddressInfo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                mservice.AddMacAddress("TestMAC");`

Comment: Can you try this code again? I just realized I didn't set the adapter of the ListView

Comment: I tried but still not working. what I found is it's not updating the UI on the acitivity. I also tried to run it in UI Thread like this `MacaddressInfo.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView txtv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
                    txtv.setText(listofMac.get(2).toString());
                    Toast.makeText(MacaddressInfo.this,"test -" + listofMac.get(2) + "- test" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });`

Comment: But there is one weird thing happens, if I put the string in toast message it displays it properly. the only thing is it's not updating any of the UI control.

Comment: actually first time it's not broadcasting, but try doing multiple times , it will come into handlemessage function and show  your log

Comment: Alright, I finally got it to work, but I'm not a fan of the solution. Will update answer in a second.

Comment: I am getting red color error at  `APIService.ACTION`

Comment: Oops, I was playing around. Change that back to `"intMAC"`